# Выбор значения по условию

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Есть функция:

```
df['valueday']=df['value']/53*df['Date']
```

, где date - количество дней в неделе. номер недели хранится в `df['Week']`

Как сделать так, что бы в случае, если `df['Week']==1` или `df['Week']==53` функция превращалась в:

```
df['valueday']=df['value']/53*7
```

?

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример входных данных и то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 1):

Без примера входных и выходных данных остается много непонятных моментов:

1. к чему упоминание `df['Week']`? В формуле и условии данный столбец не используется
2. можете пояснить что вы понимаете под неделей? Исходя из описания, неделя у вас может содержать разное количество дней...
3. Опять же судя по описанию либо `Date` это порядковый номер календарной недели, а не `"количество дней в неделе"` либо в условии должен использоваться столбец `Week`: `df['Week']=1 или df['Week']=53`

---

предположу, что в условии должен использоваться столбец `Week` (порядковый номер недели):

```
df['valueday'] = df['value'] / 53 * np.where(df['Week'].isin([1, 53]), 7, df['Date'])
```

[Документация по `np.where(...)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)